# Can iframe detect domain name from which is it loaded on?

Tags: iframe, dns

Can iframe detect domain name from which is it loaded? I want to see from which domains my widget is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the document referrer property:

```
console.log(document.referrer);
```